# Where are the inaccuracies in math.sqrt() and math.pow() coming from for large numbers?

Tags: python, pow, sqrt

If you take a number, take its square root, drop the decimal, and then raise it to the second power, the result should always be less than or equal to the original number.

This seems to hold true in python until you try it on `99999999999999975425` for some reason.

```
import math

def check(n):
    assert math.pow(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)), 2) <= n

check(99999999999999975424)  # No exception.
check(99999999999999975425)  # Throws AssertionError.
```

It looks like `math.pow(math.floor(math.sqrt(99999999999999975425)), 2)` returns `1e+20`.

I assume this has something to do with the way we store values in python... something related to floating point arithmetic, but I can't reason about specifically how that affects this case.

Comment: Similar question: [Why is math.sqrt() incorrect for large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41551529/4518341)

Comment: Note that you'll also get an exception for `n = 4503599761588224` on most machines, despite the fact that both `4503599761588224` and the floor of its square root (which is `67108864`) are small enough to be exactly representable in IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point. So it's a bit more subtle than just using numbers larger than floating-point can represent.

Comment: (BTW, I don't think the duplicate is appropriate here. There's a lot more that can usefully be said about this specific problem that isn't contained in the answers to that duplicate.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is not really about `sqrt` or `pow`, the problem is you're using numbers larger than floating point can represent precisely. Standard IEEE 64 bit floating point arithmetic can't represent every integer value beyond 52 bits (plus one sign bit).

Try just converting your inputs to `float` and back again:

```
>>> int(float(99999999999999975424))
99999999999999967232
>>> int(float(99999999999999975425))
99999999999999983616
```

As you can see, the representable value skipped by 16384. The first step in `math.sqrt` is converting to `float` (C `double`), and at that moment, your value increased by enough to ruin the end result.

Short version: `float` can't represent large integers precisely. Use `decimal` if you need greater precision. Or if you don't care about the fractional component, as of 3.8, you can [use `math.isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt), which works entirely in integer space (so you never experience precision loss, only the round down loss you expect), giving you the guarantee you're looking for, that the result is "the greatest integer `a` such that `a² ≤ n`".

Comment: I'd suggest you to add '64-bit float' to specify that larger floats would handle the larger value.

Comment: @progo: I made the note. Not relevant to base Python, where there is only `float` (64 bit C `double`), but yeah, if you had access to other floating point types (e.g. through `gmpy2.mpfr` with specified `precision`) you could perform more precise computations. Or you use the `decimal` module to get fixed decimal digit precision.

Comment: Understood. People in general have so many misconceptions about floats vs decimals I think every little bit of clarity helps

Answer (score 8):

Unlike Evan Rose's (now-deleted) answer claims, this is not due to an epsilon value in the sqrt algorithm.

Most `math` module functions cast their inputs to `float`, and `math.sqrt` is one of them.

`99999999999999975425` cannot be represented as a float. For this input, the cast produces a float with exact numeric value 99999999999999983616, which `repr` shows as `9.999999999999998e+19`:

```
>>> float(99999999999999975425)
9.999999999999998e+19
>>> int(_)
99999999999999983616L
```

The closest float to the square root of this number is `10000000000.0`, and that's what `math.sqrt` returns.