# Finding integer square root of an integer hobby code... I'm not sure if it's actually efficient

Tags: python-3.x, square-root

I am very new to this and I am trying to write a program that determines whether an integer has an integer root (or not). I have combined many different ways to narrow down the search range to find the integer root including checking the ending and binary searches. Here's the code:

```
def endingTest (num):
  print ("Now checking the input for ending that won't have integer roots")
  print ()
  endCheck = str(num)
  lastDigit = endCheck[-1]
  noIntegerSquareEnding = ["2", "3", "7", "8"]
  for digit in noIntegerSquareEnding:
    if lastDigit in noIntegerSquareEnding:
      print ("The input ends in",lastDigit,"which can't have any integer roots")
      print ("Number ending check is done \n")
      print ("No integer root found.")
      return False
    else:
      print ("Input does not end in 2, 3, 7, 8")
      print ("Input ending check is done")
      print ()
      return True
      
def binarySearch (num):    
  print ("Now checking for the range where integer root could be found")
  digits = str(num)
  count = 0
  for digit in digits:
    count += 1
  ceiling = 10**((count/2))
  floor = 10**((count/2)-1)
  high = int(ceiling)
  low = int(floor)
  print ("starting search range is between", low,"and",high)
  while high-low>10:
    mid = (low+high)//2
    if mid**2 == num:
      print ("Integer root found: ", mid, "\n")
      print (steps)
      return [False, None, None]
    elif mid**2 > num:
      high = mid
    elif mid**2 < num:
      low = mid
  print ()
  print ("Binary search is done. Search range is narrowed down to between", low, "and", high)
  return [True, low, high]

def squareTest (num, low, high):
  print ("Begin squaring every number from", low, "to", high)
  print ()
  for i in range (low, high+1):
    if i**2 == num:
      print ("Integer root found: ", i)
      return
    
    elif i**2 > num and i < high:
      print ("The root",i,"already produces a square of",i**2, "which is higher than", num)
      print ("All values from", i+1, "to", high,"are definitely out of range and therefore skipped")
      print ()
      print ("No integer root found")
      return
    
    elif i**2 < num and i < high:
      pass
    
    else:
      print ("No integer root found")
      return
      
    

def userInput ():
  try:
    userNumber = int(input("Enter an integer to find its integer root: "))
  except:
    print("That is an invalid entry. Try again.")
    return None, True
  else:
    print ("-----------------------------")
    return userNumber, False

def findIntegerRoot(testVal):
  print ("Searching for integer root of", testVal)
  print ("-----------------------------")
  if testVal < 100:
    print ("Because the number is really small, we will try squaring numbers to find root.\n")
    print ("If", testVal, "has an integer square root, it would fall between 0 and half of", testVal, "plus 1\n")
    squareTest (testVal, 1, (testVal//2)+1)
    return
  if endingTest(testVal) == False:
    return
  if testVal <= 2500:
    print ("Because the number is relatively small, we believe it's more efficient to skip binary search step.\n")
    print ("If", testVal, "has an integer square root, it would fall between 0 and half of", testVal, "plus 1\n")
    squareTest (testVal, 1, (testVal//2)+1)
    return
  proceed = binarySearch(testVal)
  if proceed[0] == False:
    return
  high = proceed[2]
  low = proceed[1]
  squareTest (testVal, low, high)
  

def main():
  repeat = True
  while repeat == True:
    testVal, repeat = userInput()
  findIntegerRoot(testVal)
  print ("----------------------------")
  print ("End of integer root search. \n")
  

main()
```

Since I am very new to programming and I'm just trying this out as a hobby, I am not sure if this program is actually efficient at finding integer root. I would imagine "efficient" means it takes the least number of steps and least amount of resources to determine the outcome. Can I please ask for some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Python is that it offers so many built-in functions in a very simple way:

```
from math import sqrt

def has_integer_root(num):
    root = int(sqrt(num))
    return root ** 2 == num
```

Choosing coding as a hobby was a great decision, you can find out more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_math.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! I was told that the math.sqrt() function would start diverging from the real value because it performs floating point operation so that's why I didn't use it in my code. Is that true? Or maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: @TimothyChang your concern about the math.sqrt() function is not wrong, however, the problem you mentioned is usually encountered with very large float numbers. This function will work in most cases. If your numbers are very large and precision is critical for the application, the binary search approach you shared above may be more accurate.  [You can find detail at similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373532/where-are-the-inaccuracies-in-math-sqrt-and-math-pow-coming-from-for-large-n). Sorry for late response.